# Delphi, Master-Detail with DetailFields in the where condition (not in select-part)

Tags: delphi, master-detail, devart, tdataset

I am using master-detail connection to show a list of assigned columns of a detail-table. In addition i want to show a second grid with not assigned detail columns

Example
Master-Table t_human: idHU, nameHU (like John, Oscar, ...)
Detail-Table t_property: idPO, namePO (like male, female, blond hair, beard, blue eyes ...)
Join-Table t_hu_po: idHU, idPO
-> John - male, blond hair
-> Oscar - male, blue eyes, beard

When i select a master table row i want to show the assigned porperties and also the not assigned ones. The master-detail for the assigned properties works fine.
But for the not-assigned properties doesn't work.

Detail-SQL:
`select p.idPO, p.namePO
from t_property p
where not exists (select * from t_hu_po hp where hp.idHU = :idHU and hp.idPO = p.idPO)`

Master-SQL:
`select idHU, nameHU from human`

When i try to select the detailfield in the delphi component (Devart, SDAC, TMSQuery) it only shows me the fields for p.idPO and p.namePO. The :idHU parameter in the statement is configured as parameter for the query in the component. When i manually type the `idHU` in the DetailFields property of the Dataset (TMSQuery) i get an *Invalid column name 'idHU'..* from delphi when activating the query.

Does someone knows a better solution than doing it with events for datachange and manually setting the detail-parameter and refreshing the detail-query. 
My thought was, that master-detail would do the same thing but only in background, so that i don't have do code it.

Thanks
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `where not exists` try  `where p.idPO not in (Select idPO from t_hu_po where idHU=:idHu)`

By makinge the subquery simply return all the idPOs that exist for the selected idHu, your query now looks for the properties that are not in that list.

Comment: The changed sql-statement, doesn't change the behavior of delphi. I don't get the field shown in Config-Dialog for master<->detail Field-selection and manually setting the fieldname in the property-editor run's into the error message  _Invalid column name 'idHU'_

Comment: This isn't a master-detail relationship, it is the exact opposite.  You are looking for the entries which are not in the relationship!